# item is not selecting in dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have one dropdown list on my asp.net page. when i am selecting an item in the dropdown list it is going to the first item of dropdown list even i set autopostback is true.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're not rebinding the list on PostBack?

Comment: Yes, rebind only if (!PostBack)

Comment: Add some code to the post then, you're not giving us much information to go on.